# SQL return distinct while sorting on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Afternoon all, hope you can help an SQL newbie with what's probably a simple request. I'll jump straight in with the question/problem.

For table `Property_Information`, I'd like to retrieve either a complete record, or even specified fields if possible where the below criteria are met.

The table has column `PLCODE` which is not unique. The Table also has column `PCODE`, which is unique and which there are multiple per `PLCODE` (If that makes sense).

What I need to do is request the lowest `PCODE` record, for each unique `PLCODE`.

E.G. There are 6500 records in this table, and 255 unique `PLCODES`; therefore I'd expect a results set of the 255 individual `PLCODES`, each with the lowest `PCODE` record atttached.

As I'm here, and already feel like a burden to the community, perhaps someone might suggest a good resource for developing existing (but basic) SQL skills?

Many thanks in advance

P.S. Query will be performed on MSSQLSMS 2012 on a 2005 DB if that's of any relevance

Comment: SQL-Server 2005? (there is no SQL-Server 2003)

Comment: Good place to learn SQL would be W3Schools http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp but don't limit yourself. Always google for more spscific answers before you post.

Comment: Wow, no, stay away from W3schools. Site full of errors. Try this one: [http://www.w3resource.com/sql/](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/tutorials.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will give you all columns for your grouped rows.

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
   SELECT 
       PLCODE
     , MIN(PCODE) AS PCODE
   FROM Property_Information
   GROUP BY PLCODE
)
SELECT p.* FROM CTE c
LEFT JOIN Property_Information p 
  ON c.PLCODE = p.PLCODE AND c.PCODE = p.PCODE
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select PLCODE, min(PCODE) from table group by PLCODE
```

you google any ansi sql site or find SQL tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    *, MIN(PCODE)
FROM
    Property_Information
GROUP BY
    PLCODE
```